# PostgreSql query with SUBSTRING

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, substring

I have a list of usernames, most of them are email addresses. I want to query the usernames with

1. Character count can't exceed 20.
2. should not include '@'.

`SELECT username, SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(username,1,strpos(username,'@')),1,20) uname from a.user_profile GROUP BY username;`

This returns the value with the '@' sign. And not getting **non** e-mail id user names.

| username | uname |
| --- | --- |
| abc.cde@pqrst.com | abc.cde@ |
| efg.hij@xyz.com | efg.hij@ |
| test1 |  |

When I try

`SELECT username, SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(username,1,strpos(username,'@')-1),1,20) uname from a.user_profile GROUP BY username;`

which affects the username that is not an e-mail address. and returning error `ERROR:  negative substring length not allowed`

Any best suggestion to handle this?

Comment: Try `SUBSTRING(username, '^[^@]*@')`

Comment: Return non-email usernames as 'null' and others with '@' sign

Comment: Do you want to select the user names that satisfy both or either of the conditions? If you want to filter, why don't you put your condition in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Not filtering, it's a type of conversion. converting all usernames into non-email user names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split_part()` to get the first part of the username:

```
select split_part(username, '@', 1) as uname
from (values ('abc.cde@pqrst.com'), ('test1')) v(username);
```

If you want only 20 characters, throw in `substr()` or `left()`:

```
select substr(split_part(username, '@', 1), 1, 20) as uname
from (values ('abc.cde@pqrst.com'), ('test1')) v(username);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8c804042548b3fb6933b96cf4ed6fdae) is a db<>fiddle.